# unicode characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

The following comparision returns true, in javascript.

`alert("café" == "caf\u00e9"); //returns true`

But if I concatenate the ASCII character "e", with the unicode value for the acute accent, and compare the equality with "é", the result is false. However, the appearance is exactly same in both the cases.

```
var v1 = "é";
var v2 = "e"+"\u0301";
alert(v1 == v2);  //returns false
```

Can someone explain the reason behind this.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between "looking" the same and "being" the same.  The second example is actually two characters - an "e" overwritten with an acute glyph, vs the e-acute glyph.

Comment: If you have modern browser that supports [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) you can use it to compare strings `const collator = Intl.Collator()` and then `collator.compare(v1, v2) === 0; //true`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: That's **really** useful information. Mind if I add it to my answer? (Or would you prefer to post an answer?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You could also use [`String.prototype.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize): `v1.normalize() === v2.normalize(); // true` (Although `Intl.Collator` appears to be slightly better supported at the moment.) I'm probably not going to post an answer, feel free to incorporate this into your answer too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can someone explain the reason behind this.

It's because they're different sequences of code units. JavaScript doesn't have a built-in matrix of every character combined with every combining mark with a mapping to equivalent single characters where they exist. (But see below...) JavaScript strings are [just sequences of UTF-16 code units](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) (except that unlike with UTF-16, invalid sequences are tolerated).

Here's what [the spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-samevaluenonnumber) about the equality of strings (Step 5a of the linked algorithm):

> If *x* and *y* are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices), return **true**; otherwise, return **false**.

As you can see, no provision there for figuring out if combining marks have combined to form a character that is also available as its own character in Unicode.

However, as [Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497576/unicode-characters-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment64395305_38497576), the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/) specification defines **collator objects** ([spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/#collator-objects) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator)). The internationalization API is tolerably-well supported in desktop browsers (Safari being the sad exception), though not on mobile browsers.

Using the default collator, your two strings are indeed equivalent:

```js
var v1 = "é";
var v2 = "e\u0301";
var equal = v1 === v2;
console.log(
  "== says: " + (equal ? "Equal" : "Not equal")
);
var equivalent;
if (typeof Intl !== "object" || !Intl.Collator) {
  console.log("This browser doesn't have Intl.Collator");
} else {
  equivalent = Intl.Collator().compare(v1, v2) === 0;
  console.log(
    "Intl.Collator says: " +
    (equivalent ? "Equivalent" : "Not equivalent")
  );
}
```